# stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_functions', when deploying an emulator in python for cloud functions

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Steps to produce.
1 create a directory for a firebase project
2 login to firebase
3 go to the project directory and in terminal use "firebase init firestore"
4 in same terminal use "firebase init functions"
5 set functions in python
6 type yes to install dependencies
7 in main.py set the default cloud functions program the installation gives you
8 in project terminal use "firebase emulators:start"

Here is the main.py of the firebase project

```
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

Here is the firebase-debug.log

```
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.521Z] Customer code is not Node
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.521Z] Validating python source
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.522Z] Building python source
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.524Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.531Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="C:\Users\thirs\Documents\PythonFirebaseProjects\pyFirebaseV1\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","python.exe","-c","\"import firebase_functions; import os; print(os.path.dirname(firebase_functions.__file__))\""]
[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.640Z] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

[debug] [2023-06-06T16:56:43.640Z] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_functions'

[error] !!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: Error: spawn "C:\Users\thirs\Documents\PythonFirebaseProjects\pyFirebaseV1\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: Error: spawn \"C:\\Users\\thirs\\Documents\\PythonFirebaseProjects\\pyFirebaseV1\\functions\\venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat\" ENOENT"}}
```

Lastly here is the terminal upon typing "firebase emulators:start"

```
PS C:\Users\thirs\Documents\PythonFirebaseProjects\pyFirebaseV1> firebase emulators:start                 
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
!  ui: Emulator UI unable to start on port 4000, starting on 4001 instead.
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\thirs\Documents\PythonFirebaseProjects\pyFirebaseV1\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: Error: spawn "C:\Users\thirs\Documents\PythonFirebaseProjects\pyFirebaseV1\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4001/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4001/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4001/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

I used the steps to reproduce, and expected the program to function correctly. When typing "pip show firebase_functions" in the project terminal, it says it is installed with the version 0.10. The python version in the project is 3.10.11, and i'm using windows.

Comment: Same issue here on firebase_functions 0.1.1

Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the reason was that I had some missing imports in my **main.py** file

The complete import is:

> from firebase_functions import firestore_fn, https_fn from
> firebase_admin import initialize_app, firestore import
> google.cloud.firestore

Now everything works fine, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Activate the python virtual environment located in the venv folder, and then run this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You have yet to install the python dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that was merged after the v.0.1.2 - this is what I read [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/issues/161)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by installing python3.11 from

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110/

then in the functions folder

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```